# Subring of a finitely generated Noetherian ring need not be Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

A common example showing that a subring of a Noetherian ring is not necessarily Noetherian is to take a polynomial ring over a field $k$ in infinitely many indeterminates, $k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$. The quotient field is then obviously Noetherian, but the subring $k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ is not since there is an infinite ascending chain of ideals which never stabilizes.

> Is there an instance of a *finitely generated* Noetherian ring over some ground ring $R$, that has an intermediate ring which is not finitely generated over $R$, and hence not Noetherian either?

Comment: This is answered by [Mariano's answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105164/are-intermediate-rings-of-finite-ring-extensions-also-finitely-generated/105218#105218). That question did not have a Noetherian condition, but it's clearly satisfied in the example.

Comment: Oh yeah, Hilbert's basis theorem shows the Noetherian condition. Should I delete this somehow?

Comment: I actually don't know what the interface for asking questions is like, but if you want to then that seems fine: no one has written an answer, or anything.

Comment: In last sentence, I think that "hence not Noetherian either " doesn't make sense ,,because Noetherian property should be checked over itself ring. (not over $R$)

Comment: By Eakin - Nagata theorem, converse is true.

Answer (score 31):

To get this question off the unanswered list, I copy Mariano's example from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105164/are-intermediate-rings-of-finitely-generated-ring-extensions-also-finitely-gener/105218#105218).

The polynomial ring $k[x,y]$ is Noetherian (by Hilbert's basis theorem), but the subring generated by $\{xy^i:i\geq0\}$ is not finitely generated over $k$.

Comment: Nice, simple example.