# Subring of a commutative Noetherian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian

We know that it's possible subring of a commutative Noetherian ring is not Noetherian (for example: [Subring of a finitely generated Noetherian ring need not be Noetherian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106122/subring-of-a-finitely-generated-noetherian-ring-need-not-be-noetherian)).

> But if $S$ be a subring of commutative Noetherian ring $R$, and $R$ is finitely generated as a $S$-module, is it true that we conclude $S$ is a Noetherian ring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is positive and moreover it's a celebrated theorem, called the Eakin-Nagata's Theorem. For a proof you can look, e.g., [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195512019).